# Why isn't back button override working in stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

According to the official doc, this is how to override the back button in react-navigation 5

```
    import { HeaderBackButton } from '@react-navigation/stack';
    <Screen
    name="Home"
    component={HomeScreen}
    options={{
      headerLeft: (props) => (
      <HeaderBackButton
         {...props}
         onPress={() => {
           // Do something
         }}
       />
     ),
   }}
  />;
```

However, when I try to implement this it doesn't work.

```
 <Stack.Screen name="Document" component={Document} options={
          { headerLeft: (props) => (<HeaderBackButton {...props} onPress={() => console.log('works')}/>)},
          { ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS }
        }/>
```

Another thing is if I put it below TransitionPreset the transition doesn't work. What am I doing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="Document"
  component={Document}
  options={{
    headerLeft: (props) => (
      <HeaderBackButton
        {...props}
        onPress={() => {
          // Do something
        }}
      />
    ),
    ...TransitionPresets.ModalSlideFromBottomIOS,
  }}
/>
```

Your first example was correct, but you had some syntax errors in the second piece of code (The type of brackets you used and where you put them).